# Membership provider and jQuery login

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using membership provider in my application and I want to log users in via a jQuery Ajax call.

How can I make a jQuery such that if authentication is successful then the authentication info is available from the asp.net membership infrastructure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your ajax call to a static WebMethod in either a WebService, HttpHandler or a page to do the server-side functionality and return it as JSON or XML. There are a lot of examples on the web on how to do this in particular, so I'll let you google those on your own. But that's the idea on what needs to happen. Just be careful what you're passing back and forth, as you don't want to just toss around authentication data for anyone to see.